# $A$ is singular and has nonzero row sums that are the same for every row. then $A+\lambda 11^{\prime}$ is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

$A$ is singular and has nonzero row sums that are the same for every row. then $A+\lambda 11^{\prime}$ is singular, where $1$ is a vector of one's.

Let $A=\{a_{i1} a_{i2}\ldots a_{i(n-1)}\space r-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_{ij}\}$ where $i$ is the row

and $A+\lambda 11^{\prime}=\{a_{i1}+\lambda, a_{i2}+\lambda, \ldots,a_{i(n-1)}+\lambda, r-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_{ij}+\lambda\}$

If I let $M_{1j}$ be the minor of $a_{1j}$ in the determinant of $A$, denoted $|A|$, then

since $A$ is singular, then

$|A|=0=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_{1j}(-1)^{1+j}|M_{1j}|+(r-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_{1j})(-1)^{1+n}|M_{1n}|$

and we want

$|A+\lambda 11^{\prime}|=0$

So far, I have

$|A+\lambda 11^{\prime}|=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(a_{1j}+\lambda)(-1)^{1+j}|M_{1j}|+(r-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_{1j}+\lambda)(-1)^{1+n}|M_{1n}|=0+\lambda \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j}|M_{1j}|$

I don't know if the minors $M_{1j}$ for $A+\lambda 11'$ are the same as the minors for $A$ here. Can I write it like this? And how do I show the last sum is 0?

Thank you

Comment: The minor $M_{ij}$ is defined to be the determinant of the $(n−1) × (n−1)$-matrix that results from $A$ by removing the ith row and the jth column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is a singular matrix, so is $A^T$, and thus there is a $u\in \mathbb R^n\smallsetminus\{0\}$, such that $A^Tu=0$ or $u^TA=0$. If now $e=(1,1,\ldots,1)$, then 
$$
0=u^T Ae=u^T \cdot(re)=r(u^T\cdot e)=0.
$$
Note that $r$ is the sum of the elements of each row of $A$, and hence $r\ne 0$. Thus $u^T\cdot e=0$.

Now, 
$$
u^T(A+\lambda ee^T)=u^TA+\lambda u^T \cdot ee^T=0+\lambda (u^T\cdot e)e^T=0+0=0.
$$
Thus $(A+\lambda ee^T)^T$ is singular, and so is $A+\lambda ee^T$, for every $\lambda$.

Comment: If $A^{T}$ is singular, why is there a non-zero vector $u$ such that $A^{T}u=0$?

Comment: @lightfish: If $A=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$  is singular, where $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are the columns of $A$,  then its columns are linearly dependent. Thus, there exist $u_1,\ldots, u_n$ such that $u_1a_1+\cdots+u_na_n=0$. But this is the same as writing $u^TA=0$, where $u=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$.)